# Help orienting myself in my SharePoint and working out the restrictions

Tags: html, wiki-pages, edit

I have an Office365 Sharepoint site which imposes some significant restrictions by the company intranet administrators.
I cannot really tell how much control I have over the content and design of the pages I can make but I certainly have been able to create a site from a group and populate it with some subsites.

I can see that I can't add any scripts but *some* HTML codes work well enough if I "edit" a page and then choose "Edit Source"

When I try to define  the contents get stripped out when I next return even though it will work in the edit preview; ie before "saving".

Thus:

```
 <style>
#p01 {
    color: blue;
}
</style>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="p01">I am different.</p>
```

Gets turned into:

```
<style>
</style>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="p01">I am different.</p>
```

and various other basic HTML like embedding youtube, calling images from the site assets work (though to what extent I can simplify the process of linking to them I have yet to determine).

Use of various things like  will be useful i.e.

```
<p>The 
   <abbr title="World Health Organization">WHO</abbr> was founded in 1948.</p>
```

So, basically I can see that I might be able to construct a decent Interactive Wiki/Learning Site but it seems that I will need to do it more or less in "Edit Source" - so I'm looking for some suggestions as to how I can explore what the limits are of my capacity to author the pages before I either give up or dive in and waste a lot of time doing things the hard way...

Answer (score 0):

In o365 SharePoint, the "Edit Source" on a page strips out the style and script contents.

I would suggest you to use `Content Editor` webpart and place your style code in there. This keeps the style content and embed it on the page.

Use page "Edit Source" for content writing only. You can use html content related tags like `<b>, <i>, <p>` etc

Comment: When you say the `Content Editor` webpart - do you mean the content editor that you get when you first click "edit" on a page - i.e. the default editing ribbon (which is very limited) on my site, or, when using the Insert tab choosing a webpart called Content Editor?  Because it seems that I have no webparts available...

Comment: `content editor` web part is not available by default in o365 Sharepoint. Thats why you cant see it in insert tab. You need to ask your admin to enable it in admin portal or using powershell cmdlet.

Comment: Thank you.  I am asking my help desk what more can be added for me to be able to author useful pages.